# Use variable as headers in data.table to do calculation

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with 10 columns.

```
library('data.table')
DT<-data.table(MA=100,MB=90,MC=80,MD=70,ME=60,TA=1,TB=2,TC=3,TD=4,TE=5)
```

Now I want to add 5 more columns, which are following the below logic.

```
New_A=MA*TA=100, New_B=MB*TB=180, ... , New_E=ME*TE=300
```

The final result should look like this

```
    MA MB MC MD ME TA TB TC TD TE New_A New_B New_C New_D New_E
1: 100 90 80 70 60  1  2  3  4  5   100   180   240   280   300
```

I am thinking using a for loop to generate the new columns but failed.

```
Alpha<-list("A","B","C","D","E")
for(i in Alpha)
{
  Col<-paste("New_",i,sep="")
  MM<-paste("M",i,sep="")
  TT<-paste("T",i,sep="")
  DT[,..Col:=..MM * ..TT] ##I know this one is wrong
}
```

How can I dynamically generate the new columns?

In real case, I have about 15 columns with suffix from "A" to "O" need to be generated which are using other columns with corresponding suffix. That's why I am thinking generating them dynamically.

Comment: not sure I follow but you might check out ?set

Comment: Could also just do `DT[, paste0("New_", LETTERS[1:5]) := .SD[, 1:5] * .SD[, 6:10]]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thank you for your reply. It works if I know the column sequence for certain. Answer given by snoram can solve all scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
Alpha <- list("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
for (i in Alpha) {
  Col <- paste0("New_", i)
  MM  <- paste0("M", i)
  TT  <- paste0("T", i)
  DT[[Col]] <- DT[, get(MM) * get(TT)]
}
```

Using set() you could also replace the last line with something like:

`set(DT, j = Col, value = DT[[MM]] * DT[[TT]])`

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

So, why don't you just add the new columns to the data table like this:

```
DT$new_A <- DT$MA * DT$TA
DT$new_B <- DT$MB * DT$TB
DT$new_C <- DT$MC * DT$TC
DT$new_D <- DT$MD * DT$TD
DT$new_E <- DT$ME * DT$TE
```

This will apply for all the rows in the data table. Hope it helps.